# Is there a URL for the latest version of a google cloud app engine deploy?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've recently done a UI update for my website, the backend is all identical.  I want to access the latest deploy (with the no-promote flag) from 'beta.my-website.com' but still access the 'normal' site from 'my-website.com'.  Ideally this would dynamically serve the latest version, but if not could I set it statically to the URL with project ID?  I have bought my domain from 123reg.  Is there a way to direct to the latest version regardless of it's traffic serving status?

**TL;DR** Can you set up a 'beta' site at beta.mywebsite.com while still being able to access the live version on [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) on google cloud?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that can be done like that.

You could deploy to a different appengine project by putting a different project id and then have `beta.mywebsite.com` route to that project instead. The nice thing about this option is everything else would be isolated (i.e. no chance of your beta changes causing bad data in your production database, or tasks in your queues)

Another option would be to deploy to a different service within your project and use your `dispatch.yaml` to route `beta.mywebsite.com` to it https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml

A third option would be to put `beta` as your version-id, and have your DNS redirect `beta.mywebsite.com` to `beta-dot-your_project_id.appspot.com`. However, when the user goes to `beta.mywebsite.com` they would ultimately see `beta-dot-your_project_id.appspot.com` in the URL bar. Also, when you're ready to go live, you would want to redeploy and promote that new version id and not promote the `beta` version-id.